# People of Oddtown

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Statement of the probelm is as follows:

There are n citizens living in Oddtown. Their main occupation was forming various clubs, which at some point started threatening the very survival of the city. In order to limit the number of clubs, the city council decreed the following innocent-looking rules:

• Each club has to have an odd number of members.

• Every two clubs must have an even number of members in common.

Prove that under these rules, it is impossible to form more clubs than n, the number of citizens.

Now , similar questions with clubs having even number of people have been asked , and even if exactly this question has been asked but i just want some guidance or thoughts on my attempt to solve this problem . Essentially, the main bit is I am trying to avoid Linear Algebra ,yet.

Attempt:

Now , the claim is that number of clubs can be maximized with n clubs .

Suppose not . Then consider such maximum arrangement in which number of clubs is maximized . Now by assumption there exist a club that has odd size     $>$$1$ . Now , take this club and form a series of club which constitutes only one person from that club for each person . Now , this "1 person clubs" can be problematic for those clubs that have the person inside "1 person club" in it , so that their intersection has 1 person which is odd . Other than that , intersection for clubs is either unchanged or size of 0 for "1 person clubs" and remaining clubs.

Now , in case there exists a problematic club , i.e a club that shares the only element of "1 person club" , then further divide that club into "1 person club"s . This obviously increases the size further . Now , there are 2 cases , either after this splitting there is no 2 clubs that have odd size intersection , in which case a arrangement with more clubs that the assumption is now made . In the other case , suppose there exists another pair of clubs which again have odd size intersection . Again , proceed by splitting this club as well . Supposing there will be another problematic club , repeat . Now , as it is assumed that in each step there will be at least one problematic club , and as each new problematic club will bring new people (otherwise that club will have 1 person but clubs are distinct ) , then number of 1 person clubs is strictly increasing . Obviously , there can be maximum of n "1 person clubs" and hence after n steps a stable arrangement with more clubs will be made

Comment: Your argument gets very vague around the point "in case there exists a problematic club , just divide it too , and search if there is another one too . At some point there will be no problematic clubs". When you later say "in the worst case" it is not at all clear that you have proved that this is the worst case.

Comment: In particular I can find 16 triples in $\{1,2,\dots,16\}$ that all have even intersection with one another.

Comment: The number of clubs can go down in the middle of this process; what if, halfway through, you encounter a "problematic" club all of whose singleton subsets are already clubs? Then you will have to delete it without compensation. So it's possible that there's no contradiction at the end, if the process stabilizes with fewer clubs than it started with.

Comment: @ Jamie Radcliffe , with an edit , I elaborated what I thought